# Procura no Datatables no modo serverSide

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

Estou quase finalizando um projeto e falta melhorar a pesquisa do Datatables.
Uso o modo serverSide e a pesquisa do ajax é esse:

```html
<?php
 /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/
 include "../../Conexao/config.php";
 mysqli_select_db($config, $database_config);
 mysqli_set_charset($config,"utf8");
 /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/

 // storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
 $requestData= $_REQUEST;

 $columns = array( 
  // datatable column index  => database column name
  0 => 'id',
  1 => 'data_criacao', 
  2 => 'razao_social',
  3 => 'Nome do Usuário',
  4 => 'categoria',
  5 => 'cidade',
  6 => 'uf',
  7 => 'status' 
 );

 $table  = "tb_empresas";
 $campos = "id, data_criacao, razao_social, CodCli, categoria_base, cidade, uf, status";

 // getting total number records without any search
 $sql           = "SELECT $campos ";
 $sql.=" FROM $table";
 $query         = mysqli_query($config, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($config));
 $totalData     = mysqli_num_rows($query);
 $totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.

 $sql           = "SELECT $campos ";
 $sql.=" FROM $table WHERE 1=1";
 if(!empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   
  // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
  $sql.=" AND ( id LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' "; 
  $sql.=" OR data_criacao LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
  $sql.=" OR razao_social LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
  $sql.=" OR CodCli LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
  $sql.=" OR categoria_base LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
  $sql.=" OR cidade LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
  $sql.=" OR uf LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
  $sql.=" OR status LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
 }

 $query         = mysqli_query($config, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($config));
 $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
 $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
 /* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */ 

 $query         = mysqli_query($config, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($config));
 $data          = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  
  // preparing an array

  $nestedData = array(); 

  $nestedData[] = "";
  $nestedData[] = "";
  $data_reversa = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row["data_criacao"]));
  $nestedData[] = $data_reversa;
  $nestedData[] = $row["razao_social"];
 
  $sql_7 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT SQL_CACHE nome, sobrenome FROM tb_clientes WHERE CodCli = '".$row["CodCli"]."'") or die(mysqli_error($config));
                         
  if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_7) <= '0'){
   echo "";
  }else{
   while($r_sql_7 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_7)){
    $cliente_sel = $r_sql_7[0];
   }
  } 
  
  $nestedData[] = $cliente_sel;
  
  $sql_5 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT SQL_CACHE categoria FROM tb_categorias WHERE id = '".$row["categoria_base"]."'") or die(mysqli_error($config));
                         
  if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_5) <= '0'){
   echo "";
  }else{
   while($r_sql_5 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_5)){
    $categoria = $r_sql_5[0];
   }
  }
  
  $nestedData[] = $categoria;
  $nestedData[] = $row["cidade"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["uf"];
  
  $nestedData[] = "";
  $nestedData[] = "";
  $nestedData[] = "";
  
  switch($row["status"]){
   case 0:
    $status_desc = 'À liberar';
   break;
   case 1:
    $status_desc = 'Liberado';
   break;
   case 2:
    $status_desc = 'Bloqueado';
   break;        
  }   
  
  $nestedData[] = $status_desc;
  $nestedData[] = "<a href=cadastro_edita.php?id_item=".$row["id"].">Editar</a>";;
  $nestedData[] = "<a href='#'>Ação</a>";
  $nestedData[] = "<a href='#'>Ação</a>";
  
  $data[]       = $nestedData;
 }

 $json_data        = array(
  "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
  "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
  "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
  "data"            => $data   // total data array
 );

 echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

Se eu pesquisar por categoria, status ou usuário, não consigo fazer.
Olhei e olhei todo o código, mas não consegui encontrar uma forma melhorar a pesquisa.

Comment: Mas dentro do SQL possui referencia para  `categoria, status e usuário`, não entendi sua pergunta, já que não é possível verificar o que está ocorrendo apenas com o que você postou.

Comment: Na parte inferior, tem esse registro:

$nestedData[] = $row["uf"];

O script consegue buscar nele, pois ele é original, vamos dizer, já veio nele.

Eu fiz esse select:

  $sql_5 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT SQL_CACHE categoria FROM tb_categorias WHERE id = '".$row["categoria_base"]."'") or die(mysqli_error($config));
                         
  if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_5) <= '0'){
   echo "";
  }else{
   while($r_sql_5 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_5)){
    $categoria = $r_sql_5[0];
   }
  }

Mas o script não consegue ler esse select.